# Mapping one string from a specific set to another string from a specific set in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm received a a string from an API and need to produce another string based on the received string.

Currently the string received from the API can be one of the following: `"customField" | "customForm" | "customAction"`). The code below shows how I'm currently doing this, however this doesn't seem very future-proof. Is there a more adaptable/ idiomatic way of doing this?

```
private getTitleFromType(
        currentType: "customField" | "customForm" | "customAction"
    ): "Field" | "Form" | "Action" | "" {
        switch (currentEditorType) {
            case "customField":
                return "Field";
            case "customForm":
                return "Form";
            case "customAction":
                return "Action";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really get around the fact that you need to store that mapping somewhere. One way of saving a bit of boilerplate is to have an object that explicitly represents your string to title mapping, then your function essentially becomes a type safe key lookup.

```js
const TitleMap = {
    a: "foo",
    b: "bar"
} as const

const strToTitle = <T extends keyof typeof TitleMap>(str: T): typeof TitleMap[T] => TitleMap[str]

strToTitle('a') // "foo"
strToTitle('c') // Error!
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=26#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgSygGwKYFkCGAHGBeGAbwFgAoGCmTALhgCIAzEEOgGjMpgCNa6vMATnTIBfKhBihIUMmSnQY0AXBCIUqfDAA8cGKgAeUVGAAmEgNaoAniAYwoV7KlvwkaLNgB8ACiW04AJS0Dk4uau44ANpwALr4nq7qHpFKMbKkSirhqN4A5Ji5ATAA9MX0TCxkmapuObnAhSVlAKICAiACAIRAA)